# Calling a viewcontroller another class from connectiondidfinish delegate NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Trying to launch a viewcontroller in connectiondidfinish delegate method of NSUrlConection

//Sprequest.m inherited from nsobject

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn {     
  NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading ");  

  if(nStatus == 401)
  { 
     NSLog(@"called maincontroller to launch dvrview");   

     MainController *mainview =[[MainController alloc] init];
     [mainview reponseFromServer];

  }    
}  
//maincontroller.m from viewcontroller
-(void)reponseFromServer
{
  NSLog(@"response from server - main controller ");

  dvrView *dvrObj = [[dvrView alloc]initWithNibName:@"dvrView" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvrObj animated:YES];
}
```

this dvr view doesnt get loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sprequest.m is inherited from NSObject , its not a viewController subclass so you cant use 

[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvrObj animated:YES];
```

inside Sprequest.m 
You can get the navigationController object from the appdelegate like this

```
((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).navigationController
```

then use

```
[((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).navigationController pushViewController:dvrObj animated:YES];
```